# Chrome google search getting redirected to bing

Tags: google-chrome, browser, malware, redirection

When I run a google search and I get back the list of the resulting pages. Sometimes if I click on one of these pages, it opens the page on a new tab and the result of the google search on the previous tab gets redirected to bing (it returns the bing results for the same search).

The redirecting to bing is done via this url: search.iseek.tools

I tried using Malware bytes to remove it, but it did not work. I would appreciate any information or help the community can provide. Thanks.

Comment: Check addons, extensions.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I looked through the extensions there aren't anything relating to this.  I don't think there is something called addons on chrome, it is probably the same as extensions.

Comment: Try running regedit and search for its name.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Thanks for that suggestion, I couldn't find anything, unfortunately.